# What is this part called? (Rear wheel lock ?)

Tags: part-identification, 4wd, differential

I need help finding how to open this part, but first I have to know what is it called.

This part is supposed to be a Lock that connects the Drive shaft to the differential on a KIA Sportage. I have been told it has three parts: 
the outer part connects to the shaft, the inner connects to the differential, and the middle one is supposed to be fixed.  The middle one couples the outer with the inner through magnetic force.

1. What's that part called ?
2. Is my description of the three internal parts correct?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I do not believe this is a user repairable item

Comment: Surely it's a diff-lock?

Comment: Is this the 2010 or newer with Magna DYNAMAX AWD

Comment: The make/model/year of the vehicle is very important to assist you.  Can you provide that information?  Cheers!

Comment: @spicetraders it seems so , even if i manage to open it, finding replacement parts won't be possible

Comment: it is 2012  sportage but not sure about the "DYNAMAX AWD"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that is a magnetically controlled clutch pack. It is similar to a limited slip differential. It is used in kia's AWD vehicles. It looks like a Jtekt ITCC active AWD unit.

[here](http://www.jtekt-na.com/assets/ce/Documents/(D1002ex)%20ITCC%20-%20Intelligent%20Tourque%20Controlled%20Coupling.pdf) is their brochure and you can see a cutaway of it half way down with the clutch pack.

yours has a different casing but should be very similar.

and the soreno uses them so it's a safe bet the sportage has them too. [jteckt in soreno](http://www.it148.com/it148-list-lvyou-19646.html)

The way this works is one side connects to either the drive line or the diff and the other side connects to the opposite (not sure if it's the "inner" or "outer" that connects to the diff and the driveline but could be either or and it would depend on model. It will work the same in either configuration). there is a powerful solenoid that can compress a pack of clutches (similar to how your air conditioning pump works). The amount of pressure is controlled by the car's computer to give more or less power to the rear wheels or none at all for fuel savings.

If I were a betting person I would say the end with the splines would connect to the diff and the flat side with the bolt holes would connect to the drive shaft then there would be a retaining plate to keep it splined to the rear diff. This would make it easily serviced without needing to disassemble the diff to get at those bolts on the flat side. but this is a guess.